# Filling a multidimensional array with random bytes in one line in C

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, random

I want to initialize a 2D matrix by filling it with random numbers (doubles).

So, for example, this code

```
#define N 1000

int main(void){
  double A[N];

  arc4random_buf(A,N*sizeof(double));

  return 0;
}
```

runs and produces a 1D array filled with random numbers as expected.

However, this

```
#define N 1000

int main(void){
  double A[N][N];

  arc4random_buf(A,N*N*sizeof(double));

  return 0;
}
```

produces a segmentation fault. I've tried initializing A with zeroes on the previous line, to no avail.

Is the only solution to use a loop here?

Edit: as Eric pointed out, stack size is likely the issue here: changing N to 600 'fixes' the 2nd code as well. Thanks!

(stack size is indeed 8 MiB on my system, so this should've fit, but there is also a 2nd array of the same size in the actual code)

Comment: [C11 Standard - 6.7.9 Initialization(p10)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p10) *"If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is indeterminate."* Use of an indeterminate value is *Undefined Behavior*. [C11 Standard - J.2 Undefined Behavior](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#J.2) "The value of an object with automatic storage duration is used while it is indeterminate (6.2.4, 6.7.9, 6.8)."

Comment: I'm guessing `&A[0][N - 1] + 1 != &A[1][0]`. What if you just have a flat 2D array: `double A[N * N]`? Or just loop it anyway...

Comment: *Is the only solution to use a loop here?* - no. You can initialize the arrays to know byte values and the "Shuffle" the arrays. [Fisher–Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) or you can loop filling each element with a random value.

Comment: @DeiDei: Arrays are required to be contiguous; Given `double A[N][N];`, then `&A[0][N - 1] + 1 != &A[1][0]` is necessarily true as a statement of where the terms must be placed (not as a C expression; it technically violates pointer arithmetic rules).

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: What does initialization or lack thereof have to do with anything here? The code in the question does not use any uninitialized object.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: What does a Fisher-Yates Shuffle have to do with anything here? The question does not ask for shuffling.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Since there was no definition of `arc4random_buf`, it initially appeared he was relying on `double A[N][N];` to fill `A` with random byte values by allowing it to remain uninitialized. If `arc4random_buf` is what is producing the random values -- then no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stacks are limited in size. 8 MiB<sup>1</sup> or smaller is common.

If `double` is eight bytes and `N` is 1000, then `double A[N][N];` requests 8 MiB. The stack in your C implementation is insufficient to provide this, so your program crashes.

Instead of declaring a local object in your function, use `malloc` to request memory. The memory available via `malloc` is generally much larger:

```
double (*A)[N] = malloc(N * sizeof *A);
if (!A) { /* Handle error. */ }
arc4random_buf(A, N * sizeof *A);
```

### Footnote

<sup>1</sup> [“MiB” stands for mebibyte, which is 2<sup>20</sup> = 1,048,576 bytes.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mebibyte)